# Sync Framework 2.1 Provisioning Multiple template for Hub-Spoke sync

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am new to Microsoft technologies and Sync framework.
I am looking for a option to improve the current implementation.
It is hub-spoke, Central SQL DB server and Android mobile clients Sqlite DB. Currently we have one Scope Template, it contains all the required tables(till now 40 tables) with parameter filter clause.
For every new client we are creating new scope based on the template provisioned on DB server. Sync we do have lot of data(10mb)for initial sync from server to client, it takes average 10 mins. what I would like to know is,

1.Can I create 2 Templates? for Example 20 tables for one template scope the other 20 tables for 2nd template scope? if yes means,

- I would like to do initial sync completion with 2 web service call. 2 web service call to get 2 template scope in 2 different times.
  for example 1st web service call i would request half of the data which ever data are required to for bi-directional sync and later 2nd call would be remaining data(download only direction) to complete initial sync per client.

could you please help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am assuming you're using the Sync Framework Toolkit. you should be able to create multiple templates and multiple scopes from them.

Comment: Thanks JuneT. I would like to know am I going the right direction?  creating 2 templates and 2 scopes for every client to sync with respect to my scenario mentioned in my question. I am following below link to generate scopes and template. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1889.tutorial-creating-and-consuming-a-wcf-sync-service.aspx

Comment: breaking up a scope into multiple ones is in the right direction. not only for performance, different tables has different characteristics, some are readonly, frequently updated, seldom updated, etc...

Comment: Thank you, I am able to create multiple template and scopes